# Loss function that penalizes under-predictions more than over-predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, regression, loss-function

I have a regression problem where I am predicting a continuous variable. Loss functions used most often in these cases (RMSE, MAE, etc.) don't treat over- or under- predictions differently.

I am in a scenario where under-predicting would be a much worse outcome than over-predicting.

What type of loss function would appropriately capture this?

Comment: Use something like RMSE but multiply by alpha > 1 if it's an  under prediction and by 0 < beta < 1 if it's an over prediction?

Comment: Can the business cost of failed predictions be made explicit in your case? You might be able to make your business cost per example (or a transformation of it) the loss function, instead of a test metric.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'under-' and 'over-' predictions are, but if you mean that your data is unbalanced towards a certain class, I suggest using Infogain Loss matrix to counter that

Answer (score 1):

Pick an asymmetric loss function. One option is [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) (linear but with different slopes for positive and negative errors).